# Arrays.toString() returns [Ljava.lang.String;@2f67d81

Tags: java, arrays

When I use `Arrays.toString()` on the string `aryLines`*, it returns:
`[Ljava.lang.String;@2f67d81` What am I doing wrong, Am I print ing the exact memory location and not the array itself? If so, how do I print the contents of the array?

*The array aryLines is equal to `<example><XML><tags>`

Comment: You probably printed out the array itself and not the String result from `Arrays.toString`. However this is only a "hunch" since a proper SSCCE (eg. enough information to reproduce the problem) isn't provided. As such this problem is Unclear.

Comment: you need to iterate over each of the values in the array, not the array itself

Comment: What kind of array is that? `(buck)(bucky)...`? Never seen such representation. Do you have array of array BTW?

Comment: please try search on SO or google pls [here from SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-an-array)

Comment: the parentheses represent tags ( for < and ) for > because it interpreted it as HTML

Comment: <buck><bucky>buck</bucky></buck> is one index in the array.

Comment: @Zorian Thanks, that was my problem +1

Comment: give the complete code regarding this problem .....

Comment: @Nitroman np but one hint next time try google or SO search before^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are printing it wrong, the toString() of any object just prints a textual representation of the given object you called the function. so it means that if you call Array.toString it will print  [Ljava.lang.String;@2f67d81 this is the textual memory representation of the object. a very good way to solve this is to use a List, its way more friendly than arrays, and you can print them really easy. if you need arrays just use this

```
String[] aryLines;
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(aryLines));
```

this should give you a proper output of the elements contained in your array

Comment: Thanks! This solution to my problem is better than the other thread.